# Automatic Weights Different on one side than the other

Tags: armature, weight-painting

*see title*

Whenever I use automatic weights on my model it always has one side different than the other on legs, feet, arms, and hands. The topology is exactly the same on both sides and I've already removed doubles and recalculated normals. Please help. It's a pain to have to go back every time and manually adjust the weighting

feet example:

good
[image: The good side]

bad

[image: The bad side]

and arms example:

good
[image: good side]

bad

[image: bad side]

Comment: do you have pre-existing vertex groups?

Comment: Nope. None whatsoever. Just to be sure I deleted all the current vertex groups from my mesh and tried parenting it with the rig again. Same thing.

Comment: Have you tried applying Rotation and Scale(Object mode transformations), not doing so can introduce serious errors into several tools.

Comment: Suspect backwards normals on the model's right side.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to related to the fact that you have multiple disconnected parts (meshes) inside a mesh object. It always gives Blender trouble to auto-weight multiple-part meshes.

Two solutions, as far as I can see it:

1. Separate each sub-object within the object (Edit mode - Select - Ctrl+P - By loose parts).  Then apply automating weighted-painted solution to each part separately. (Of course, before doing that, delete the armature modifier, weight painting, and the existing vertex groups on the original mesh)
2. Even easier - if your mesh is 100% symmetrical, simply delete half of it, apply the weight painting, THEN mirror. The mirror side will have the exact same w.p. as the other one. Of course, it will still retain the potential w.p. errors due to disconnected meshes, but at least both sides will be identical.