# Automatic weights don't seem to work properly on the mirrored side of my model

Tags: bones, weight-painting

I seem to have the same issue as [Automatic Weights Different on one side than the other](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29211/automatic-weights-different-on-one-side-than-the-other)
which doesn't seem to have a solution.

I've tried removing and reapplying the automatic weights on both sides and consistently the Right (mirrored) side doesn't add the weights properly while the Left (original) side does.

here's a gif showing the hind legs of the model on both sides [image: hind legs gif]

Is there a solution to this bug yet? (assuming that it is a bug of some sort)
I'm using 2.79, I think it has something to do with the mirroring process or the bone roll but I really can't say for sure.

If i have to manually assign weights to the meshes is there any way to make the them act the same on both sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your mesh is strictly symmetrical, there's one easy solution to this. Just delete one half, apply the weight-painting, then add the mirror modifier (and apply it, if needed). Now both halves are identical, weight painting included.

Comment: You then would have to rename the vertex groups to the mirrored bones to reassign them. 
Didn't realize I could do that.