# Automatic weights are not symmetrical when applied to my mesh

Tags: mirror, vertex-weights

I've been trying to parent a rig I made to a mesh, and for whatever reason, the vertex groups are asymmetrical. Both the armature and the mesh are perfectly symmetrical, so I don't understand why the automatic weight painting isn't. The bone on one side conforms perfectly to the arm it's assigned to, while it's exact copy on the other isn't painted the same.

[image]
[image]

According to [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/252025/why-weight-paint-is-not-symmetrical-in-the-mirror-plane), the problem can be solved by enabling the X mirror in the "Make Parent" submenu. However, when I do this, it makes the weight painting on both sides of the model broken, instead of fixing it.

[image]
[image]

So, how do I solve this? Am I just going to have to manual fix the weight painting for each bone?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I know it's literally 10 minutes later, but I fixed my own problem. I tried to use the mirror modifier like in the post I mentioned, and it seemed like it didn't work. Turns out I screwed up the mirroring somehow. Using the mirror modifier totally works.